For what values of $c$ is there a straight line intersecting $x^4+cx^3+12x^2-5x+2$. at $4$ points
For what values of $c$ is there a straight line intersecting $$x^4+cx^3+12x^2-5x+2$$. at 4 points
Let the points of intersection be $(a,f(a)), (b,f(b)),(e,f(e)),(d,f(d))$
By the mean value theorem , there are tangents parallel to the chord joining
$(a,f(a)); (b,f(b))$
; $((b,f(b)), (e,f(e))$,
and $(e,f(e)) , (d,f(d))$
in the relevant intervals
where $a<b<e<d$
Let the slope of the line be $m$
We then have to have 3 distinct solutions to $m=4x^3+3cx^2+24x-5$
This requires this cubic to have 2 turning points, so $12x^2+6cx+24=0$ needs to have $2$ distinct solutions.
Thus $|c| > 4\sqrt{2}$
however, this doesn't guarantee $3$ roots for the cubic.
How do I guarantee that ?
I have seen this answer here
But I'm nor sure I understand it.

There are two "c"'s in the question. The unknown parameter and the $x$-coordinate of the third point of intersection. Change the notation. You should also put $a,b,c,d$ in some order.

You might want to use the discriminant of the cubic instead

What about the tangent parallel to the chord passing through $(a,f(a))$ and $(c,f(c))$, and the one passing through $(b,f(b))$ and $(d,f(d))$, etc.

@Medo , I didn't they they were relevant to solving the problem, are they

@ChrisLewis, I don't know that, so I'd ideally want to derive it, which isn't pretty, is there no way around that

The key going forward is to recognise that the cubic relation must have three real roots for some value of $m$, not for all values. Lines will intersect the quartic function at four points only if they have a slope within the range where the cubic relation from the first derivative does have three real roots.
To prove that some such line exists, we seek a value of $m$ that lies in range. Let $x_0$ be a root of the cubic relation
$g(x)=4x^3+3cx^2+24x-(m+5)$
with the requirement that the derivative of the cubic, which is the second derivative of the quartic, is negative at $x=x_0$. Then for some $x=x_1>x_0$ we will have $g(x_1)<0$, but with the positive leading coefficient of the cubic polynomial we must also have $g(x_2)>0$ for some $x=x_2>x_0$. So there must be a second root for $g(x)=0$ that lies between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and thus is greater than $x_0$. By a similar argument, the cubic also has a third root less than $x_0$.
So if we identify
$g'(x)=12x^2+6cx+24=12(x+\frac{c}4)^2-\frac34(c^2-32)$
as negative when $x=-c/4$ and $c^2>32$, we can plug in
$m=4(-\frac{c}4)^3+3c(-\frac{c}4)^2+24(-\frac{c}4)-5=\frac18(c^3-48c-40),$
and assure that some lines with that slope will intersect the quartic at four points.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Here's an answer based on the observation that if the  polynomial
$$
f(x)\ed x^4+cx^3+12x^2-5x+2
$$
has two distinct points of inflection, then the straight line through those two points must intersect the graph of $\ f(x)\ $ at two other distinct points.
The function $\ f\ $ is convex over any region where its second derivative $\ g(x)\ed 12x^2+6cx+24\ $ is non-negative, or concave over any region where its second derivative is non-positive.  If the second derivative has no real roots, or only one double root, then it's everywhere non-negative and therefore the polynomial itself is everywhere convex and no straight line can intersect it in more than two points.  This occurs if and only if the discriminant of $\ g\ $ is non-positive—that is, if and only if $\ c^2\le32\ .$
On the other hand, dividing $\ f(x)\ $ by $\ \frac{g(x)}{12}=x^2+\frac{cx}{2}+2\ $ gives
\begin{align}
f(x)-&\left(\frac{c^3}{8}-6c-5\right)x-\frac{c^2}{2}+18\\
&=\left(x^2+\frac{cx}{2}+2\right)\left(x^2+\frac{cx}{2}+10-\frac{c^2}{4}\right)\ .\\
\end{align}
Therefore, if $\ c^2>32\ ,$ then the straight line$\,^\color{red}{\dagger}$
$$
y=\left(\frac{c^3}{8}-6c-5\right)x+\frac{c^2}{2}-18\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
intersects the graph of the polynomial wherever $\ x\ $ is one of the four distinct roots
\begin{align}
&\frac{-c-\sqrt{5(c^2-32)}}{4}\\
&\frac{-c-\sqrt{c^2-32}}{4}\\
&\frac{-c+\sqrt{c^2-32}}{4}\\
&\frac{-c+\sqrt{5(c^2-32)}}{4}
\end{align}
of the polynomial
$$
\left(x^2+\frac{cx}{2}+2\right)\left(x^2+\frac{cx}{2}+10-\frac{c^2}{4}\right)\ .
$$
It follows that there's a straight line intersecting the graph of $\ f(x)\ $ at four distinct points if and only if $\ c^2>32\ ,$ and when this condition holds \eqref{1} is the equation of such a straight line which intersects the graph
at the points whose abcissas are given above.
$\color{red}{\dagger}$ This is the straight line through the two distinct inflection points of $\ f(x)\ $ at $\ x=\frac{-c-\sqrt{c^2-32}}{4}\ $ and $\ x=\frac{-c+\sqrt{c^2-32}}{4}\ .$

So, we have to characterize real $c$ for what there exist real $a,b$ such that the polynomial $x^4+cx^3+12x^2-5x+2-ax-b$ has four distinct real roots, that is the polynomial $p(x)=x^4+cx^3+12x^2-5x-ax$ attains some real value four times. It is easy to check that the latter holds iff its derivative $p'(x)=4x^3+3cx^2+24x-5-a$ has three distinct real roots. We can choose $a$ to provide this iff the derivative $p''(x)=12x^2+6cx+24$ has two distinct real roots. The latter holds iff the discriminant $36c^2-1152$ of $p''(x)$ is positive, that is iff $|c|>4\sqrt{2}$.

That's what I did, yes, however, as I mentioned in my question, this doesn't guarantee 3 roots for the cubic, just 2 turning points.

@Alex Ravsky The sentence "that is the polynomial $p(x)=x^4+cx^3+12x^2-5x-ax$ attains some real value four times" does not make any sense! Any polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ takes infinitely many real values. You mean to say "has four real roots.."

@mathandphysicsforever Since we have a freedom to choose the parameter $a$, given the cubic, we look not for its roots, but for the horizontal lines intersecting the graph in three distinct points. It is easy to check that such a line exists iff there are two turning points.

Let us fix $c\in\Bbb R$. OP shows that if a line intersects the graph of the quadric $x^4+cx^3+12x^2-5x+2$, then $|c|>4\sqrt 2$.
The question is about the opposite direction, using analysis (differentiation) is preferred instead of algebra (discriminant) from the comments. Here is an answer using the derivative.
Assume $|c|>4\sqrt 2$. OP already claims, it is enough to show that there exists an $m\in\Bbb R$ so that the cubic (polynomial (function)) $4x^3 + 3cx^2+24 x-5-m $ has three distinct real roots. I will use equivalently $n$ for the constant coefficient, so let us consider the function
$$
f_n(x) = 4x^3 + 3cx^2+24 x +n\ .
$$
Then $f_n'(x) = 12 x^2 +6cx +24$ does not depend on $n$, and it is a function with two different real roots, since the discriminant is positive, $(6c)^2-4\cdot 12\cdot 24=6^2(c^2-32)>0$. (Here the discriminant has a less involved algebraic meaning, it can be obtained by forming a square...) Let $a_1<a_2$ be the two roots of $f_n'$. Then $f_n'$ is

positive on $(-\infty,a_1)$,
negative on $(a_1,a_2)$, and
positive on $(a_2,\infty)$.

This information can be traced back to $f_n$, which is correspondingly:

strictly increasing on $(-\infty,a_1]$,
strictly decreasing $[a_1,a_2]$, and
strictly increasing on $[a_2,\infty)$.

This implies $f_n(a_1)>f_n(a_2)$.
We may change $n$ now by vertically translating the graph of $f_n$, so that for the "new $n$", abusively denoted by the same letter from now on, the zero is in the interval between these values,
$$
f_n(a_1)>0>f_n(a_2)\ .
$$
Observe now that there is (at least) one root of $f_n$ in each of the open intervals mentioned above. (Darboux property of a continuous function, intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.) So we have three roots for the cubic $f_n$ for a suitable $n$.
